# MYSQLI Multi tables won't work

Tags: php, variables, mysqli

Im trying to make a query that taks a variables from on other table,

SQL table1

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `table1`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table1`;
CREATE TABLE `table1` 
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `naam` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44145 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

SQL Table2

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `table2`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table2`;
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `txt` text,
  `naam` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44145 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

.

```
<?PHP
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT 10";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $naam = $row["naam"];   
    }
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE naam = '$naam'";
    $result2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);
    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $txt = $row2["txt"];        
        echo''. $txt.' ';

    }
?>
```

But is not working How do I solve this?

EDIT: add the tables from the MYSQL database.

Comment: You know that you overwrite the variable `$naam` every iteration ?

Comment: So? How do I solve this?

Comment: @TomLammers - For the `$naam` variable overwriting you can declare it as an array outside the `while()` loop and then, inside it, you assign it like this `$naam[] = $row["naam"]`... But if you want to execute the second query as many times as the results of the first, you have to run the entire second `while()` loop (even the `$sql2` declarement) inside the first loop.

Comment: What is the current result, and what is the desired result? Are there any errors being thrown?

Comment: there is no column with name naam in table 2.  What you want to do. please explain. do you want to get data from both table or what ? @TomLammers

Comment: Ow sorry! I update now the sql ;)

Comment: Your table design is not good @TomLammers.

Answer (score 1):

This query will help you out. it will return text column from table2 when table2.naam=table1.naam condition will meet.

```
SELECT table2.txt FROM table2, table1 WHERE table2.naam=table1.naam
```

Hope it will help you. Happy coding

Comment: but @tom lammers is trying to do same thing. as i understand

Answer (score 0):

why not like that:

```
<?PHP
    $sql = "SELECT t2.txt FROM table2 AS t2 WHERE t2.naam IN (SELECT t1.naam FROM table1 as t1 LIMIT 10)";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $txt = " " . $row["txt"]. " ";        
        echo $txt;
    }
    $result->free();
?>
```

You avoid to ask 2 time database query... loop for nothing..

Comment: Past sql describe table into your question and say what you want clearly because my sql works with your question.. So edit to add information

Comment: If its a real code.. It should be works. What you want to do exactly.. My code take 10 entry of the first table... Extract the naam.. And select txt in the second db where naam appear in the first query..